# Show that there is no vector field with transitive orbit on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields

I need to show that there is no vector field with transitive orbit on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Let $X:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$ a $C^{k}, k\geq 1$, vector field in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.
The integral curves of $X$ are the solutions $\phi_{p}(t)$ of the system $x'=X(x)$ through the point $p\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ defined on its maximal interval $I_{p}$

The orbits of $X$ are the sets $\gamma_{p}=\{\phi_{p}(t):t\in I_{p}\}$.

A transitive orbit of $X$ is a dense orbit of $X$, i.e., $\bar{\gamma_{p}}=\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Is there some theorem that I can use to solve my question? I tried to suppose that $X$ has dense orbit and get a contradiction, but I didn't got anything.

Comment: It appears that yes, there is such a theorem, namely the [Poincaré–Bendixson theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Bendixson_theorem). But it is not clear (to me, at least) how to pass from that theorem to the non-existence of transitive orbits.  A correction: perhaps not the Poincaré–Bendixson theorem itself, but ideas from its proof ([Jordan curve theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem))?

Comment: @user539887 Usually this idea or technique is called "Bendixson bag" (at least in Russian literature) and it is based on Jordan theorem. If $\gamma_p$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is recurrent to itself. Pick any point $p$ at such trajectory: there is always a small transversal segment $l$ along which all trajectories go in the same direction. Also, at some time $T$ point $\phi_p(T)$ lands on $l$. If you now join ${l}$ with $\bigcup_{t \in \lbrack 0,  T\rbrack} \phi_p(t)$, you'll get a closed curve, and $\phi_p(t)$ stays in the domain enclosed by it for all $t > T$.

Comment: [This picture](http://w.ict.nsc.ru/books/textbooks/akhmerov/ode/s-12/s-12-02.gif) roughly illustrates the concept.

Comment: @Evgeny As far as I understand, the OP allows a negative semiorbit. But this should not a big obstacle: there would be a smaller "Bendixson bag" (for negative times) inside the larger "Bendixson bag" (for positive times), and points inside the smaller bag would be reached neither for positive nor negative times. Incidentally, perhaps you could write a full answer?

Comment: I'll probably write a full answer, but it requires drawing a good illustration and finding a reference to Bendixson bag in English literature. So, it takes some time, and if you want to do it -- I have nothing against it :)